# Akka scalability and performance benchmark testcases

Tags: performance, scala, scalability, akka

I have been looking for a testcase which can showcase the "SCALABILITY" of Scala/Akka.

i referred to the akka-actor-test/akka.performance.trading test case, but it seems like a Unit Test case rather than a performance benckmark test case.

I have run simple akka Actor based Ping-Pong test case which gives 650K pin-pong per second in the same JVM. But it goes down to 2K ping-pong per second if i make them as remote actors running in different JVM on the same machine.

But i guess this is not enough to showcase why someone should use Scala instead of Java. The same test case if run in Java may give better results. so why someone should go for scala based akka actors? **which is that test case scenario which if written in C++/Java will not scale beyond a certain point and for which Scala is more suitable?**

is there such a test case available in Github? i have seen jboner/akka-bench but it seems very old (last update seems 3 years ago). is there any other which i am missing? if yes, please share it to me. if not, kindly suggest the scenario , i will develop the test case and upload to github.

Comment: Have you read this: http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single-machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Benchmark that tests message sending throughput and message exchange latency in the same JVM for different actor libraries written on Scala (Akka vs. Lift vs. ProxyActors vs. Scala vs. Scalaz): https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors

Comment: This answer would be even more helpful if a representative highlight of the five results were posted...not everyone is going to want to pull the project, compile it, etc..  Especially since you wrote the tests, you probably have some insight into what they show.

Comment: Great idea! I will try do it.